# C++ - Is there a way to overload designated initializers?

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, constructor

Let's say there's a `struct` type that will be used used to hold the coordinates of a Point in 3D space.

This could be defined like:

```
struct Point { double x, y, z; };
```

Making use of `double` values because we want to be as precise as possible.

An instance of this `struct`, could be declared using designated compound literals, like:

```
double x = 0.0;
double y = 0.0;
double z = 0.0;
...
Point p = (struct Point){ .x=x, .y=y, .z=z };
```

However, when trying to declare another Point starting from different types:

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int z = 0;
...
Point p = (struct Point){ .x=x, .y=y, .z=z };
```

The compiler throws an error, because it's unable to find a suitable constructor. This works if one does:

```
Point p = (struct Point){ .x=(double)x, .y=(double)y, .z=(double)z };
```

Is there a way to overload the Point constructor, so that one does not have to *manually* cast each member of the initializer list to double?

Perhaps using something like `Point(initializer_list<int> ...) {}` in the `struct`'s declaration?

Comment: I think that the `{ .x=x, .y=y, .z=z }` syntax is from C, not C++, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but constructors/overloading belongs to C++, unless I'm out of date.

Comment: I would just make a `std::initializer_list<T>` constructor.

Comment: That sounds good. Care to share how?

Comment: Are you okay with a C++11 or above answer?

Comment: Absolutely. "4 more characters to go"

Comment: @almosnow Looks like C++11 does not support designated initializers at all: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731707/why-does-c11-not-support-designated-initializer-list-as-c99) and [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859213/what-is-the-c-equivalent-to-cs-designated-initializers), so I doubt it's possible to overload them. Anyway, would be happy to learn otherwise.

Comment: @yeputons Wow, didn't knew that... that's kind of lame. I always thought of C++ as being some kind of superset of C.

Comment: Also, compiles fine in clang.

Comment: @almosnow That is a compiler extension.  Nothing forbids them from adding it you just have to know that it reduces the portability of the code.

Comment: @almosnow: C and C++ are distinct languages, none is a superset of the other. Even identical syntax does not imply identical semantics. That's why double-tagging for both is not well received here. To be clear: don't add a C tag for C++ questions and vice-versa!

Comment: *That's why double-tagging for both is not well received here.* Yeah no, it is completely justified. It actually applies to **both** languages. Not really in a mood to argue, see you around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not doing to be able to overload the designated initializer list as that is [not a supported C++ feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731707/why-does-c11-not-support-designated-initializer-list-as-c99) but by using a constructor and C++11's uniform initialization you can get pretty close to what you want.  If we have

```
struct Point { 
    Point (double x, double y, double z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}
    double x, y, z; 
};
```

Then we can use it like

```
int main() {
    double x = 0.0;
    double y = 0.0;
    double z = 0.0;

    Point p{x, y, z};
    Point i{1, 2, 3};
}
```

Comment: @almosnow: It's already [voted in for C++20, apparently](https://botondballo.wordpress.com/2016/07/06/trip-report-c-standards-meeting-in-oulu-june-2016/). With some limitations, relative to C.