# C++ error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization

I looked at the earlier questions but still i was not satisfied, hence i am posting this.
I was trying to compile the C++ code written by someone else.

```
/*
file1.h
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct
{
    struct
    {   
        unsigned member1;
        unsigned  member2; 
    } str1;

    struct
    {
        unsigned member3;
        unsigned  member4; 
    } str2;

    struct
    {
        unsigned member5;
        unsigned  member6; 
    } str3;
} CONFIG_T;



/* 
file1.c
*/
CONFIG_T  cfg =
{
    .str1 = { 0x01, 0x02 },
    .str2 = { 0x03, 0x04 },
    .str3 = { 0x05, 0x06 }
};
```

Compiled with std C++11 and i get below error. Why the '.' has been used in code 
while      assigning values ?

```
home $$  g++ -c -std=gnu++0x  initialze_list.cpp

initialze_list.cpp:34: error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token

initialze_list.cpp:35: error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token

initialze_list.cpp:36: error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token
```

I was not able to understand the reason for error. Please help.

Comment: which lines are number 34,35,36?

Comment: You've been given C code, not C++ code. Try a C compiler.

Comment: You are not the first person having this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/855996/1025391

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you posted is C code, not C++ code (note the .c file extention). However, the following code:

```
CONFIG_T  cfg =
{
    { 0x01, 0x02 },
    { 0x03, 0x04 },
    { 0x05, 0x06 }
};
```

should work fine.

You can also read about  C++11 initialize lists in the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Initializer_lists).

Comment: But my requirement is i have to compile the source as C++ for ARMv7 embedded processors. Since other files were compiled with C++ options i have to compile the above mentioned code also in  C++.  It works with C Compiler, but i want it to compile in C++  :(

Comment: Yes, I cant change the code. The above code is exact copy with member/structure names changed. Please help me to compile the source in C++. The exact Compile command i am using is :                                                      
    $ /bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-c++ -O3 -std=gnu++0x -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon -ffast-math   file.c

Comment: Is it not compiling as C++? Even though this is written as C code, it looks like it should compile fine as C++ (except for the lines that were causing an error, but I'd never write that in C), although you may get warnings about your header names being deprecated.

Comment: @Eric Finn: `except for the lines that were causing an error` -> Exactly.

Comment: @AshokaK: If you insist on compiling the code as C++ the you will have to port it from C to C++.

Comment: @AshokaK: You must change the code *or* compile it as C. *Why* do you have to compile it as C++? There shouldn't be a problem mixing C and C++ as long as the C declarations are `extern "C"` when C++ sees them, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Designated aggregate initializers is a C99 feature, i.e. it is a feature of C language. It is not present in C++.

If you insist on compiling it as C++, you'll have to rewrite the initialization of `cfg`.

Answer (score 1):

```
/* 
file1.c
*/
CONFIG_T  cfg =
{
  .str1 = { 0x01, 0x02 },
  .str2 = { 0x03, 0x04 },
  .str3 = { 0x05, 0x06 }
};
```

That code is using a C99 feature called **designated initializers**. As you have observed, that feature is not available in C++ and C++11.

---

As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/856026/1025391) you should use a C compiler for C code. You can still link it to your C++ application. You could use `cmake` to do the build configuration for you. A simple example:

```
/* f1.h */
#ifndef MYHEADER
#define MYHEADER

typedef struct { int i, j; } test_t; 
extern test_t t;

#endif
```

---

```
/* f1.c */
#include "f1.h"
test_t t = { .i = 5, .j = 6 };
```

---

```
/* f0.cc */
extern "C" { #include "f1.h" }
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << t.i << " " << t.j << std::endl;
}
```

---

```
# CMakeLists.txt
add_executable(my_executable f0.cc f1.c)
```

just run `mkdir build; cd build; cmake ..; make` from your source directory.

Comment: @ moooeeeep ...

Thanks for that. Will check on the solution.

As somebody said "Hammers for nails, screwdrivers for screws ...
 For Humans ... ?   :) :)"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all ...

After all the analysis i found that the above code has C99 feature called
**Designated initializer**.

To compile this code in C++ i have changed the code to normal initialization as below.

==========================

```
/*
 *  initialze_list.cpp 
 */

#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    struct
{   unsigned member1;
    unsigned  member2; 
} str1;
struct
{   unsigned member3;
    unsigned  member4; 
} str2;
struct
{   unsigned member5;
    unsigned  member6; 
} str3;
} CONFIG_T;

CONFIG_T  cfg =
{
 { 0x01, 0x02 },
 { 0x03, 0x04 },
 { 0x05, 0x06 }
};
/* End of file  */
```

==================================

This code compiled properly without the error in C++.

$$ g++   -c     initialze_list.cpp

$$ g++   -c     -std=gnu++0x    initialze_list.cpp

Comment: you should accept [SingerOfTheFall](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11395350/1025391)'s answer then I think.