# How to make indexing into arrays less error prone?

Tags: c++

Is there a way to use enum elements to index into an array in a way that minimizes indexing errors.

Example:

```
enum class Index : int {
    Foo, Bar, Koo
};

static const int Values[] = { 42, 7, 3 };

constexpr int GetValue(Index i) {
    return Values[int(i)];
}

auto v = GetValue(Index::Foo);
```

The problem with the above is that modifying either Index or Values may cause indexes to point to wrong values, and such errors would not be detected by the compiler.

Comment: Can we assume things are a bit more dynamic, so trivialities like `enum class Index : int { Foo = 42, Bar = 7, Koo = 3};` aren't viable?

Comment: or just `constexpr int Foo = 42; constexpr int Bar=7; constexpr int Koo=3;`?

Comment: Honestly, the more I experiment with this, the more it sounds like you don't have an array of ints.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ebf7e7c72fa6428 is as close as I could get, but it's not perfect. It lets you add an `Index` without initializing it's array value, and then you can access out-of-bounds after that :(

Comment: Choosing ints for the Values is just for the example code. In reality, each entry is a complex object with lots of init data. Also, there are alot of entries.

Comment: I was looking for something like the following, but it's not supported by C++/MSVC: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581074/explicit-indexes-in-c-array-literals

Comment: Is there a reason not to use a map?

Comment: For reducing errors when iterating over elements of an array, it's better to not use indices at all - for example, iterating over ranges specified in terms of `begin()` and `end()` iterators of standard containers.  For having alternative names for particular elements in a container, there are maps.

Comment: @MikelF: I was asking for this in the general case, because I wanted to know to do it for builtin arrays. But, the const map version does work for my usecase. So, it's good that you pointed that out.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a final enum value to count total number of enumerations will do the trick, assuming your enumerations are 0, 1, 2, ... etc.

```cpp
enum class Index : int {
    Foo,
    Bar,
    Koo,
    NUM_INDICES // 3
};

static const int Values[Index::NUM_INDICES] = { 42, 7, 3 };
```

Comment: Not 100%. It can't ensure the right number is at the right index, and if you leave out numbers in `Values` they get zero padded at the end. About all this can do is error out if too many values are supplied and maybe issue a warning if too few.

Comment: Also missing a cast. Can't use a member of an enum class as a array size without a bit of help.

Comment: Remember that `enum` declarations don't have to be contiguous; there can be gaps.

Comment: Since your enum is declared as an integer, one can insert "Kaz = -1`, to the top of the list for some interesting behavior.