# What is the array initialization style in this code? Is it standard?

Tags: c++

I came across a source file [here](https://github.com/hishamhm/htop/blob/8a147dd5b4bc35feebb14a3a55ee44186ce3cea4/linux/LinuxProcess.c#L139) (in C). It uses a reasonable-but-strange style to initialize an array. I gave it a try in a shorter C++ program (please notice the "old way" in the code's comment):

arr.cc

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    long arr[] = { [0] = 100, [1] = 101 }; // old way: long arr[] = { 100, 101 };
    cout << arr[0] << " " << arr[1] << endl;
}
```

The code is compiled like this:

> g++-6 -std=c++14 arr.cc -o arr

When run, the output is this:

```
100 101
```

It passed with `-std=c++14`? But I can't find it in a C++ reference website, like cppreference.com. Does it conform to the standard? If so, since which version?

Comment: It doesn't conform, it is a GCC extension.

Comment: Compile with `-pedantic` and check the warnings. https://godbolt.org/g/rG3LXC As I said, it is an extension from the compiler vendor.

Comment: @DeiDei Just tried (`-std=c++14 -pedantic -Wall`).. it passed. FYI, my GCC is 6.3.0.

Comment: This initialization syntax is specific to C language. It is not currently supported in C++ (might be in the future). GCC allows it in C++ code as an extension.

Comment: Perhaps older GCC versions don't give out the warnings, but yeah... Designated initializers are a C feature that GCC happens to support in C++ as well. It isn't in any C++ standard.

Comment: Designated initializers are part of C99, but [they haven't made it into C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/855996/364696).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not valid C++ code; the C standard adopted it, and as an extension GCC allows it in C++ as well. To get GCC to conform to the C++ standard, you need to pass both `-std=c++17` (or whatever version) *and* `-pedantic`. With that, [your code does emit warnings saying it's nonstandard](https://godbolt.org/g/PbZHr1). The description of how this works in GCC is [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html#Designated-Inits).

---

Note that you can also do this with `struct` members, not just arrays; given

```
struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

you can say `Point p = {.x = 17}`. This is also nonstandard in C++ so far, but [it will be adopted in C++2a](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Designated_initializers). This only applies to the non-array version so far; I don't know if there are plans to add the array version as well or if it will happen by C++2a.